# UIImage picker gives me a black screen when I take a photo and want to use it

Tags: camera, uiimagepickercontroller, coreml, coremltools

I am building a coreML app that identifies flower type.
When I implemented the UIImagePicker and using it through my phone it allows me to open the camera and takes the photo but when I click to use this photo it just gives me a black screen.

I have attached my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAVuH.png).

Answer (score 0):

**Possible cases:**

1. UIImagePickerController is not in the main thread.

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       #put your code here
       imagePicker.delegate = self
       imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
       ....
   }
   ```
2. Set privacy setting for the camera to info.plist for accessing camera:

   ```
   <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
   <string>This app wants to take pictures.</string>
   ```